# Custom ProgressBar in kotlin

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-custom-view, kotlin

I'm trying to make a custom `ProgressBar` the way I did custom layouts a lot before. This time I'm having issues.

**I can achieve the desired look with just this xml:**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar" />
```

**The ultimate goal, however, would be doing some of the customization in the custom class so the xml shrinks to this:**

```
<se.my.viktklubb.app.progressbar.HorizontalProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/planProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Here is the custom class:**

```
class HorizontalProgressBar : ProgressBar {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        initialSetup()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        initialSetup()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        initialSetup()
    }

    fun initialSetup() {
        max = 100
        isIndeterminate = false
        progressDrawable = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_bar)
    }
}
```

Second constructor gets fired but the bar isn't styled. It actually appears as indeterminate spinning progress and none of these setup gets applied eventually - feels like those are overriden later by something else.

What's wrong here?

**DISCLAIMER:**
This is a very simple example. I'm perfectly aware I could go for styles or a simple xml implementation but I just use this simple case only to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the bullet 5 of this [article](http://ivankocijan.xyz/writing-a-maintainable-custom-view-in-android/), you may need to modify initialSetup:

```
fun initialSetup() {
    max = 100
    isIndeterminate = false
    progressDrawable = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_bar)
    invalidate()
    requestLayout()
}
```

If it doesn't change anything, try calling initialSetup later, on onResume of activity/fragment for example. If this work, the problem is maybe linked to the complexity of initialization/lifecycle of android components.

Comment: Link is dead. :(